# Error: cannot convert 'char (*)' to 'const char*'

Tags: c++, string

Tengo este código de c++ y quiero guardar la función strcmp en una variable para poder declararla desde main, pero al momento de compilar obtengo: ***[Error] cannot convert 'char (*)[41]' to 'const char*' for argument '2' to 'int strcmp(const char*, const char*)'***

¿Alguien puede corregirme o decirme si lo que intento es posible? Gracias!!!

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>


int main(void)
{  

char nombres[5][41];
char nom[41];
 int f,t,existe=0;
 t = strcmp(nom,nombres);


for(f=0;f<5;f++)
{
    printf("Ingrese el nombre de persona:");
    gets(nombres[f]);
} 



printf("Listado completo de nombres\n");
for(f=0;f<5;f++)
{
    printf("%s\n",nombres[f]);
}




printf("Ingrese un nombre para buscarlo:");
gets(nom);
for(f=0;f<5;f++)
{
    if (t==0)
    {                            
    
    existe=1;
    }
    
}



if (existe==1)
{
    printf("El nombre se encuentra almacenado en la matriz.");
}
else
{
    printf("El nombre no se encuentra almacenado en la matriz.");
}

getch();
return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

En el código falta usar strcmp() para revisar si el string ingresado para búsqueda corresponde a uno de los almacenados. Esto se debe hacer después de haber ingresado las cinco personas.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>


int main(void)
{
    char nombres[5][41];
    char nom[41];
    int f,t,existe=0;
    //t = strcmp(nom,nombres);  Esta linea no es necesaria

    for(f=0;f<5;f++)
    {
        printf("Ingrese el nombre de persona:");
        gets(nombres[f]);
    }

    printf("Listado completo de nombres\n");
    for(f=0;f<5;f++)
    {
        printf("%s\n",nombres[f]);
    }

    printf("Ingrese un nombre para buscarlo:");
    gets(nom);
    for(f=0;f<5;f++)
    {
        if (strcmp(nombres[f], nom) == 0)
        {
            existe=1;
        }
    }

    if (existe==1)
    {
        printf("El nombre se encuentra almacenado en la matriz.");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("El nombre no se encuentra almacenado en la matriz.");
    }

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

El strcmp tiene el siguiente formato:

```
int strcmp ( const char * str1, const char * str2
```

Si observas el primer y segundo  parámetro es un `const`, por lo tanto , cuando haces  `strcmp(nom,nombres)`   estás poniendo como parámetro un `char*` y ya vimos que debe ser un `const char*`. Para solucionarlo solo haz un `cast`:

```
     strcmp((const char*)nom,(const char*)nombres[0])
```

Nota: Nombres es un arreglo de 2 dimensiones para el strcmp necesitas al menos ponerle la dirección del primero nombres[0]